# Elif condition not executed

Tags: python, json, flask

So I'm trying to do some json request with Postman. This is my code:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def index():
        news_site = request.get_json()
        print(news_site)
        if news_site.get('kompas', True) & news_site.get('detik', True) == True:
            scrapdata = kompas_fun(), detik_fun()
            return jsonify(scrapdata)
        elif news_site.get('kompas', True) & news_site.get('detik', False) == True:
            scrapdata = kompas_fun()
            return jsonify(scrapdata)
        elif news_site.get('kompas', False) & news_site.get('detik', True) == True:
            scrapdata = detik_fun()
            return jsonify(scrapdata)
        else:
            return jsonify({'value': 'error'})
    return app
```

The `if` condition works, but don't know why that two `elif` conditions ignored then just go directly to `else` when the input is `kompas=True, detik=False`, or `kompas=False, detik=True`. I already tried without `== True`, replacing `&` with `and` but still same. And here is the result of `news_site` print and terminal output:

```
(env) PS D:\demotest> flask run
 * Serving Flask app "run.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 318-319-173
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
{'kompas': False, 'detik': True}
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2020 20:05:48] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'kompas': True, 'detik': False}
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2020 20:06:03] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'kompas': True, 'detik': True}
```

The first and second input resulting `else` output. But the third one executed perfectly. I dont understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `&` is bitwise and. Use `and`

Comment: Still same result. First time I use `and` before trying to use `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is a binary operator, not a logical operator. Are you maybe looking for

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    news_site = request.get_json()
    kompas = bool(news_site.get("kompas"))
    detik = bool(news_site.get("detik"))
    scrapdata = []
    if kompas:
        scrapdata.append(kompas_fun())
    if detik:
        scrapdata.append(detik_fun())
    return jsonify(scrapdata)
```

Comment: Nice simplification, but missing the `else` case. You could do `return jsonify(scrapdata or {'value': 'error'})`...